# Bash CLI: Is there a way to simultaneously create and set permissions on a file without repeating the filename?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

Is there a way to simultaneously create and set permissions on a file without repeating the file name?

I tried:

```
touch text.txt && chmod u+x text.txt
```

This gives me permission denied when I run it and I want to know how to fix it and: How do I get rid of the repetition?

Comment: You can use `umask` to set the default file permissions for any file you make in shell instance you run it in. That said, your command shouldn't cause an error. What permissions do you have on parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting a permissions error when you run your command, that suggests that you do not have permissions to create files where you're trying to create the file.  Regarding the rest of your question:

As BroLow said, you can use `umask` to affect the default permissions of files created in your session.  However, this can be inconvenient, particularly if you only want the new permissions in effect for a single command.

You can use the `install` command to create and set permissions on a file:

```
install -m <mode> -o <owner> -g <group> <srcfile> <destination>
```

If you want to create an empty file, you can use `/dev/null` as a source:

```
install -m 644 /dev/null <destination>
```